# reading multiple xml file from a folder and printing some attribute using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read multiple xml file from a folder and want to get tag attribute for further processing.
So far i have tried many available examples but no luck so far.

below is my code, any help will be appreciated..! Thanks..!

```
 foreach (glob("unzip_temp/other/newfolder/*.xml") as $filename) {
    $xml_file = file_get_contents($filename, FILE_TEXT);

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
    foreach ($xml->tag1 as $fileinfo) {

        $name = $fileinfo['Name'];
        $language = $fileinfo['Language'];
        $creator = $fileinfo['Creator'];
        echo "<li> $name ,$language ,$creator";
    }
```

below is the part of xml file that i want to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<tag1 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="Bethanien_Befunder_CTKolon"  Language="other" Type="Simple" Creator="ADMINISTRATOR" IsMultiSelect="false" IsFloatingPickList="false" IsPhraseGenerated="false">
```

Comment: It seems you have missed one bracket tag }

Comment: You have several problems in your script. First, `file_get_contents` doesn't receive the constant `FILE_TEXT` as a second parameter, it should be [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Second, `simplexml_load_file` requires a path to a file, but not its contents, that you get with `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: Thanks anyways

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();


        foreach (glob("unzip_temp/other/newfolder/*.xml") as $filename) {


            $doc->load($filename);
            $intros = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tag1");

            foreach ($intros as $intro) {
                echo "<br />";
                $name = $intro->getAttribute('Name');
                echo $name;
                echo "<br />";
    echo $intro->getAttribute('Creator');
   echo "<br />";
   echo $intro->getAttribute('Language');
  echo "<hr />";
            }
        }
```